# Microsoft.Adapters.SAP properties not listed in the filters section when creating a send port

Tags: biztalk, sap-erp, sap-basis, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to set up a windows 7 64bit enterprise machine as a BizTalk development machine. Everything works well except..

I've installed the necessary adapters from the BizTalk installer, I've also installed the SAP 7.2 adapters as it has been done on the server.

The problem is that when I am trying to create a send port and define my filter I cannot find Microsoft.Adapters.SAP. properties in the drop down.

It is available in the server but not in my development machine. Any clues?

Comment: More information needed: What edition of your BizTalk server? Are you referring the WCF-SAP adapter shipped with BizTalk?

Comment: Apologies, It's BizTalk Server 2013 R2, and yes it's the adapter that ships with BizTalk.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the Assembly with the SAP Adapter Properties is not deployed to the Group during Setup.  Why?  Who knows, but it's always been like that.

You have to manually add Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.BiztalkPropertySchema.dll and they'll show up.  I always add it to the BizTalk Application 1 Resources but you can put it in any Application.

You will have to add a Reference to use those props in any Port Filter.

Be sure to check GAC on Add.

Answer (score 0):

I missed something when looking at our current setup on the server. 
On the application itself you have to go to resources and Add the BizTalk SAP adapter dlls from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack\bin

I ended up adding;
- Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.BizTalk.dll
- Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.BiztalkPropertySchema.dll
- Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll

And sure enough the properties now appear in the filters section of the send port.