# SQL Server error - error code 0xC0208449 while running package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, sap-erp

After executing the SSIS package I got the following error

> sql server error error code 0xC0208449

I am running the package in verbose mode and got this is the full package log:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Started:  9:28:24 PM
Log:
     Name: OnPreValidate
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPostValidate
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: PackageStart
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Beginning of package execution.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Based on the system configuration, the maximum concurrent executables are set to 8.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: DiagnosticEx
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: <?xml version="1.0"?><DTS:ParameterValues xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"/>
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPreExecute
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPreExecute
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPreValidate
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPostValidate
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDataInitialize::GetDataSource(NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ConnectionString: Data Source=MSMWRLDWHSRV;User ID=msmdbadmin;Initial Catalog=SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;,...)'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IDataInitialize::GetDataSource succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDBInitialize::Initialize'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IDBInitialize::Initialize succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDBCreateSession::CreateSession'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IDBCreateSession::CreateSession succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: User:ExecuteSQLExecutingQuery
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Database connection acquired.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:27
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:27
End Log
Log:
     Name: User:ExecuteSQLExecutingQuery
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Preparing SQL statement:TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_EKPO
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:27
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:27
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDBCreateCommand::CreateCommand'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IDBCreateCommand::CreateCommand succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'ICommandText::SetCommandText'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'ICommandText::SetCommandText succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IGetDataSource::GetDataSource'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IGetDataSource::GetDataSource succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'ICommandProperties::SetProperties'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'ICommandProperties::SetProperties succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDBProperties::SetProperties'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IDBProperties::SetProperties succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'ICommand::Execute'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'ICommand::Execute succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: User:ExecuteSQLExecutingQuery
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Execution of the SQL statement is completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:27
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:27
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnProgress
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Executing query "TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_EKPO".
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Progress: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.85
   Source: Truncate_temp_table 
   Executing query "TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_EKPO".: 100% complete
End Progress
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'ITransactionJoin::JoinTransaction'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: MSMWRLDWHSRV.SPN_SASBI_TAT_DB.msmdbadmin
     Source GUID: {0721083F-6FFA-44BD-AF36-B2EE91592E3C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'ITransactionJoin::JoinTransaction succeeded'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPostExecute
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Truncate_temp_table
     Source GUID: {E5511F00-A7D6-45D7-AD9B-9A5524CC6E6F}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPreExecute
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPreValidate
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnInformation
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Validation phase is beginning.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnInformation
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Validation phase is beginning.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Info: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.85
   Code: 0x4004300A
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: Validation phase is beginning.
End Info
Log:
     Name: OnProgress
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Validating
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Progress: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.85
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table 
   Validating: 0% complete
End Progress
CustomEvent: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.85
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table 
   Name: OnPipelinePreComponentCall
   Description: Data flow engine will call a component method.
End CustomEvent
Log:
     Name: OnPipelinePreComponentCall
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Data flow engine will call a component method. : 2 : EKPO 1 : AcquireConnections
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: SAP PROD
     Source GUID: {D579EA65-6C64-4CB7-8BD4-6A1C847A86B3}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IDbConnection.Open(ConnectionType: Microsoft.Data.SAPClient.SAPConnection, Microsoft.Data.SAPClient, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
ConnectionString: ASHOST=172.31.24.108;SYSNR=00;CLIENT=500;USER=MBLUSR;LANG=EN;)'.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: Diagnostic
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: SAP PROD
     Source GUID: {D579EA65-6C64-4CB7-8BD4-6A1C847A86B3}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ExternalRequest_post: 'IDbConnection.Open failed'. The external request has completed.
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {D579EA65-6C64-4CB7-8BD4-6A1C847A86B3} with the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.".

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {D579EA65-6C64-4CB7-8BD4-6A1C847A86B3} with the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.".

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Error: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Code: 0xC0208449
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table EKPO 1 [2]
   Description: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {D579EA65-6C64-4CB7-8BD4-6A1C847A86B3} with the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.".
End Error
CustomEvent: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table 
   Name: OnPipelinePostComponentCall
   Description: Data flow engine has finished a call to a component method.
End CustomEvent
Log:
     Name: OnPipelinePostComponentCall
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Data flow engine has finished a call to a component method. : 2 : EKPO 1 : AcquireConnections : 131603327068594730 : 131603327069034813
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: EKPO 1 failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: EKPO 1 failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Error: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Code: 0xC0047017
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: EKPO 1 failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.
End Error
Log:
     Name: OnProgress
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: Validating
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Progress: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table 
   Validating: 33% complete
End Progress
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: One or more component failed validation.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: One or more component failed validation.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Error: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Code: 0xC004700C
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: One or more component failed validation.
End Error
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: There were errors during task validation.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: There were errors during task validation.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Error: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table 
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Log:
     Name: OnPostValidate
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnPostExecute
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: Insert_SAP_Table_TO_Temp_Table
     Source GUID: {9B2F4821-4457-473E-84C4-4BCA457C6ED4}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: OnWarning
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Warning: 2018-01-13 21:28:26.90
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: TATRptIncremental 
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
Log:
     Name: OnPostExecute
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: (blank)
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: DiagnosticEx
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: <?xml version="1.0"?><DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"><DTS:PeakWorkingSetSize>216653824</DTS:PeakWorkingSetSize></DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage>
     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
Log:
     Name: PackageEnd
     Computer: MSMWRLDWHSRV
     Operator: MSMWRLDWHSRV\localadminl1
     Source Name: TATRptIncremental
     Source GUID: {1889B904-7BC5-410C-9D17-C7017342E78C}
     Execution GUID: {6E32BB73-A583-40E9-AE44-E6C30775D9D4}
     Message: End of package execution.

     Start Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
     End Time: 2018-01-13 21:28:26
End Log
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  9:28:24 PM
Finished: 9:28:26 PM
Elapsed:  2.469 seconds
```

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com) to learn more about asking good questions, accepting answers and other website rules. Also to get your the *"informed"* badge.

Answer (score 0):

The main error you encoutered is

> ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {D579EA65-6C64-4CB7-8BD4-6A1C847A86B3} with the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.".

That mean that you have to assign this assembly `Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll` to the GAC on the deployment machine.

Make sure that you have already installed both 32 and 64 bit versions of the Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack.

**Additional Information**

- [Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib) Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll’ or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. (Microsoft.Adapters.SAP)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2016/11/22/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-mscorlib-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-adapters-sap-sapginvoker-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-specified/)
- [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPGInvoker.dll'](http://geekswithblogs.net/MoonWalker/archive/2013/07/17/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft.adapters.sap.sapginvoker.dll.aspx)
- [BizTalk Server 2013 R2: WCF-SAP Adapter Step-by-Step Installation Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31030.biztalk-server-2013-r2-wcf-sap-adapter-step-by-step-installation-guide.aspx)
- [How to: Install an Assembly into the Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac)
- [Microsoft.Adapters.SAP properties not listed in the filters section when creating a send port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776378/microsoft-adapters-sap-properties-not-listed-in-the-filters-section-when-creatin)